# How to create screenshots on a 'clean' OS?

Tags: screenshot, software-design

I am an individual developer and I wish to showcase some of my software to upload to my website. However, my C drive is obviously littered with different files, most of which for development, which I don't want to be featured in the screenshots.  I preferably would like  to screenshot my software on a 'clean' install of Windows 7 without any clutter.

How to create this type of screenshots, etc.? The lower cost the better.

Comment: [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) and an actual clean Windows installation.

Comment: @millimoose I didn't know if there was an accepted way to do this among developers or anything? Normally there is an easy way and a hard way.

Comment: That's begging the question *twice*. **1.** Most developers don't care whether other people see their crap in screenshots. **2.** "an easy way and a hard way" is a thing they say in crime shows when interrogating suspects. When programming there's the *right* way which becomes apparent as you figure out what you actually need doing. (In this case: you want a clean `C:\`? Create a new one.) When you get rid of the cliches, what you need is "a way" seeing how you don't have one at all.

Comment: @millimoose I do see your point and you are right. I do need "a way" because I wasn't actually aware of my options. Thank you for your help - VirtualBox appears to be my solution, as I do care about your point #1 for various reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh VM seems like it would be your best bet. From the fact that you said C drive I'll assume you're on Windows. If you have Windows 8 you can install Hyper-V from the control panel. If not, use something like Virtual Box (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Using a VM means you will not only have a completely clean Windows installation, but also a completely clean file system.

Comment: Yes, I have Windows 7 though, so I'll have to use something like VirtualBox. If I have a genuine version of Windows 7, how can I install Windows 7 on VirtualBox

Comment: Just googled this: http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/how-to-install-windows-7-in-virtualbox-guide-hatryst

Comment: @Andy Just use it unactivated while you make your screenshots.

Comment: I suppose this is an option, although not the best, I will have to live with it with my limited resources.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new user account on windows, that should get rid of a lot of clutter.

Comment: One of my applications lists folders in the root directory, and there are things like 'eclipse' and 'texlive' in there. Is there any easy way to 'hide' these?